# pandas - another SettingWithCopyWarning: I am using .loc to replace specific values, but still get the warning

Tags: python, pandas

I thought I followed the best practice:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'cond':['a', 'b', 'a'], 'value':[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]})

mask = df.cond == 'a'
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'] * (-1)
```

In essence, is condition is met, replace a value with it's negative. What is the better way to perform this operation so I do not trigger the warning?

Comment: Solution is nice, is possible share data before `mask = df.cond == 'a'` ? Maybe some filtering, then need `copy`  like `df = df[df['a'] == 1].copy()`

Comment: For me it wroking perfectly, no `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: Also is possible use `df.loc[mask, 'value'] *= -1`

Comment: weird ... did not nest on the simplified code ... but get the warning on real example, that is too complex to share. maybe the problem is elsewhere. Also not getting the warning on the simplified code :/

Comment: @jezrael thank you .. in the real world, df is a created as `df = df2[['cond', 'value']]` . adding `.copy()` to this, fixed the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out not to be with the code as shown. That code example worked fine.

In the real world, `df` is a created as follows: `df = df2[['cond', 'value']]` . adding `.copy()` to this line, fixed the warning.

This solution was pointed our by @jezrael in the comments.